# ImageGrab Python on OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library, imagegrab

I want to use a imageGrab in my application.
My laptop is a macbook with OSX.

When I use Pillow I got this error:

```
ImportError: ImageGrab is Windows only
```

Code:

```
import ImageGrab

im = PIL.ImageGrab.grab()
```

but in Pillow documentation says:

```
The current version works on OS X and Windows only.
Take a snapshot of the screen. 
The pixels inside the bounding box are returned as an “RGB” image on Windows or “RGBA” on OS X. 
If the bounding box is omitted, the entire screen is copied.
```

http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html

When I use pyscreenshot I got this error:

```
IOError: cannot identify image file '/var/folders/wk/b1c839t15xvbz923wtfdsfw80000gn/T/pyscreenshot_imagemagick_Gsb0Pw.png'
```

Code:

```
import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab

im=ImageGrab.grab()
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me, especially when the documentation so clearly contradicts the actual function. I'd file a report with the developers to let them know.

Comment: @esqew [Those docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html) are the latest, and generated from the latest, master branch source. The [2.9.0 docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/2.9.0/reference/ImageGrab.html) say it's Windows only.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [commit history](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/commits/master/PIL/ImageGrab.py), OSX support was only added on 1st Aug 2015. However, the latest Pillow release (2.9.0) was made on 1st July 2015. So it would appear that the online documentation is not kept in sync with the current release.

You could compile a pre-release version from github to get the required functionality, but it would probably be much simpler to just copy the relevant [ImageGrab code](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/ImageGrab.py) directly:

```
import os, tempfile, subprocess
from PIL import Image

def grab(bbox=None):
    f, file = tempfile.mkstemp('.png')
    os.close(f)
    subprocess.call(['screencapture', '-x', file])
    im = Image.open(file)
    im.load()
    os.unlink(file)
    if bbox:
        im = im.crop(bbox)
    return im
```

Comment: Sorry, we need to do a better job with associating documentation with releases.

Comment: Or rather, we need to do a better job managing which releases we display on RTD. A little late, but I've made the default 2.9.0 for now: https://pillow.readthedocs.org/. Tomorrow we'll update to 3.0.0 (I'll make a note in our release documentation about this, too: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/developer.html#release.)

Answer (score 1):

The next Pillow release, 3.0.0, is due out on Thursday (1st Oct 2015) and `ImageGrab` will support both OS X and Windows.

The [linked documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageGrab.html) is the latest, and is generated from the latest master branch.

The [2.9.0 docs](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/2.9.0/reference/ImageGrab.html) says it's Windows only.

Answer (score 0):

OS X support was added in [Pillow 3.3.0](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/3.0.0/PIL/ImageGrab.py#L22).